# tshark: using frame contains and write to file

Tags: tcp, wireshark, sniffing, tshark

i want to filter out TCP packets that contain a specific string in the frame data (data.data)

```
tshark -i 1 -f "tcp port 8800" -Y "frame contains FILE"  -w "data.txt"
```

This is exactly what i want.

Unfortunately, I'm receiving an error message telling me that I can't write to file and use a display filter at the same time, and i wonder if there's a workaround for this?

Or Can this be achieved with some other package analyzer like ngrep?

Thanks a lot

Comment: Odd, the manual page specifically says that `-Y` is meant for filtering before writing to a file...

Comment: `tshark: Display filters aren't supported when capturing and saving the captured packets.`
thats the error message i'm getting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

well i ended up using a node.js module to solve this problem.

https://github.com/mscdex/cap